# Rebol iterated face- truncating text

Tags: rebol, rebol2

Using this code:

```
view layout [
    t: text-list  "this line truncated> lfkjsdflksjfslfsdjfsdlldskjflsdkfj" with [
        text-pane: func [face id][
            if pair? id [return 1 + second id / iter/size] 
            iter/offset: iter/old-offset: id - 1 * iter/size * 0x1 
            if iter/offset/y + iter/size/y > size/y [return none] 
            cnt: id: id + sn 
            if iter/text: pick data id [
                iter/font/color: 255.0.0
                lines: at data id 
                iter
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

All text beyond 'this line tuncated>' doesn't show up on the display window.
How do I get around this?

Comment: Sorry you didn't get a response, it seems our [chat room feed](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/291/rebol-and-red) was broken.  But...here's a reminder that, hey, we have a chat room.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of painful digging here is how to NOT have the text-list truncate words from your
list. Add the "**para: [ wrap?: false ]**" line as shown below:

```
view layout [
    t: text-list  "this line truncated> lfkjsdflksjfslfsdjfsdlldskjflsdkfj" with [
        text-pane: func [face id][
            if pair? id [return 1 + second id / iter/size] 
            iter/offset: iter/old-offset: id - 1 * iter/size * 0x1 
            if iter/offset/y + iter/size/y > size/y [return none] 
            cnt: id: id + sn 
            if iter/text: pick data id [
                iter/font/color: 255.0.0
                lines: at data id 
                iter
            ]
        ]
        para: [ wrap?: false ]
    ]
]
```